# Can I change a CSS variable using code behind?

Tags: css, asp.net

Using the new (currently 2016) CSS variables or "custom properties", is it possible to dynamically change a variable using code behind?  If so, how?

In my CSS stylesheet file I have;

```
:Root 
{
  --Back-Color: #FFFFFF;
  --Fore-Color: #0000CC;
  --Border-Color: #3300CC;
  --Highlight-Color: #FFE900;
}
```

How can I access and change the actual color values (such as #FFFFFF) using the "code behind" in asp.net?

Comment: i think that's `impossible`, alternatively you can declare a new `class` with new `variable` and use that `class` instead of the `one` you don't want to use :)

Comment: Keep in mind CSS is designed to be cached on the client so even if you can achieve this you will have to overcome caching issues.

Comment: Currently I have a website with 7 different "themes" and each theme has its own CSS stylesheet.  So every time I add a new item that needs to be "themed", I have to update all 7 stylesheets.  What I WANT to be able to do is just change the "root" variables in a single stylesheet depending on which theme is selected.  If we can't do that, what's the point of the CSS variables?  I mean, I realize they can eliminate some repitition, but...

Comment: @Jon P  Thanx, I wasn't aware that CSS was cached on the client.